# How to get element from list A and list B using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

How to get element from list A and list B using LINQ EVEN if list B is empty (will still return element of list A but elements of list B will be empty)

The idea is to be able to recreate a single anonymous object based on elements of list A and B.

```
From elemListA In data.ListA_
From elemListB In elemListA.ListB _
   Select New With { _
         .ElementA = elemListA.ElementA, _
         .ElementB = elemListA.ElementB, _
         .ElementC = elemListB.ElementA, _
         .elementD = elemListB.ElementB, _
   }).ToList()
```

**The problem is that it will crash if ListB is empty.. and another problem is if i put a where it will not include the elements of ListA because they are filtered out by the where clause and i want to have them.**

I would do a join but the problem is there no relation between the two object.. except an element from ListA have a ListB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surprisingly tough to get an outer join effect when no join is possible. Basically, I can see two approaches:

1. Replace `elemListA.ListB` by an array with one empty (`Nothing`) element when `ListB` is null.

   ```vb
   Dim array(0) as Nullable(of ElementB)
   ...
   From elemListB In If(elemListA.ListB, array)
   ```
2. Use `Union`: first query the `ListA` objects that have a `ListB` and union with the object that haven't. In both queries you must create exactly the same anonymous types, so in the second part you must put `.ElementB = emptyB` where `emptyB` was declared by `Dim emptyB As ElementB = Nothing`.

Comment: I fixed my problem by adding an empty item in the second list. So solution 1 is easy to me and have been accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're describing is a left outer join. Microsoft [wrote a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx) on doing this with LINQ.

Specifically addressing your question, you need to check for a null value. In their example, Microsoft uses a ternary operator to return an empty string if the value is null.

```
var query = from person in people
                    join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                    from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ?    String.Empty : subpet.Name) };
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you introduce.. person equals pet.Owner which mean you need a reference from pet to owner. In my case i don't have such reference and i can't have one.